# How can I match the country names of two different DFs in R?

Tags: r

Since df1 is the main dataset I would like to know the country names that it has also exist in the df2. And if it does not exist I would like to put it into a list then I can check whether or not it has a slightly different name (sometimes it is just "the" is missing) in the df2. Basically I do not want to rename every single country names, I only want to rename that are different.

Comment: i think you're looking for setdiff and/or intersect function from dplyr package

Comment: `setdiff(df1$country_names, df2$country_names)` will list names that are in `df1` but NOT in `df2`; `setdiff(df2$country_names, df1$country_names)` will do the opposite (names in `df2` that are not in `df1`). See the manual: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html